# do i need to sign my app before submitting to app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, code-signing

do i need to sign my app with my distribution provisioning profile before submitting to app store? also tell me do i need to add entitlement as we do in ad hoc or simply build with app store distribution provision profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do i need to sign my app with my distribution provisioning profile before submitting to app store?

Yes. You need to build the app with an iPhone Distribution Provisioning Profile associated with your distribution certificate. If you haven't already, you'll need to create a new Distribution Provisioning Profile that has its Distribution Method set to App Store.

> do i need to add entitlement as we do in ad hoc or simply build with app store distribution provision profile?

Yes. Just like with Ad Hoc distribution, you need an entitilements.plist with the `get-task-allow` unchecked.

If you already have a configuration in Xcode for your Ad Hoc build, creating an App Store build configuration should be just a case of duplicating the As Hoc configuration and changing the code signing settings to use the App Store provisioning profile.

Comment: ennuikiller has linked to the Apple docs for building apps for distribution. In there it says "For App Store Distribution, skip [the entitlements bit]".